# DYNAMIC SQL - Report builder Don't create parameter + fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters, reportbuilder

```
DECLARE @table as NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[Credit].[Cards]'
 
DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT 
    [Card Type]
,   [Card Owner]
,   [Card Number] FROM' + @table + 'WHERE ' + '[Card Type] = ''SuperiorCard'''
    

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

• When I use the above inside Microsoft Report Builder I get 3 fields created and everything works fine. But I need SuperiorCard to be a parameter.

• If inside SSMS I create a Variable @Customer at the top and do ... '[Card Type] = ''''+@Card+''''...  it works fine and it choose card type based on that variable.

• So now I delete declared variable and transfer this to Microsoft report Builder and builder creates the @Parameter but can't see the fields.

• I do ... '[Card Type] = '+ CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),@Card)... and it also create parameter but not the fields and I also can't manually connect the fields. The fields are only created when [Card Type] is hardcoded in a string.

I know this looks like using DYNAMIC SQL is not needed but this is just an example. If I get this I can apply it to my project.

Could you Help please? I need to know how to make this work. I am new to SQL and bad at SQL terminology yet - would be very great if you can explain using human words, how should this code look like in order this to work?

Many thanks in advance

Inside builder, I did try to put the code with hardcoded string so I get the fields and then I change the code to the one that creates the parameter but this don't work. It creates parameter and remove fields.

Comment: The above would result in `FROM[Credit].[Cards]WHERE`

Comment: Which is valid syntax, @Stu , if not very ideal. Try `SELECT * FROM[sys].[databases]WHERE database_id > 4;`

Comment: *"But I need SuperiorCard to be a parameter."* Then why aren't you using it as one? `sys.sp_executesql` allows you to pass parameters to it. Why are you using "dynamic" SQL here anyway, when the value of `@table` appears to be static.

Comment: Yes @ThomA I suppose the point though is that this relies on always delimiting every object name regardless which is a potential bug that could easily be averted.

Comment: Why I said "If not very ideal", @Stu .

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for this problem
Create the parameter afresh in report builder, name it as @cardType and change the data type to text.

In your Sql query, use the name parameter above when you want to filter by card type

```
DECLARE @table AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[Credit].[Cards]'
 DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT 
 [Card Type],
 [Card Owner],
 [Card Number] FROM ' + @table + ' WHERE [Card Type] = @CardType';
```

then go to report builder and map the cardtype parameter to the dataset

If you have the new Powerbi, you should be able to create paginated report right inside the Powerbi report.